# auth token for discord with requests

Tags: python, networking, python-requests, discord

I am trying to get my auth token for discord with request.

```
payload = {
        "captcha_key": "null",
        "gift_code_sku_id": "null",
        "login": "email",
        "login_source": "null",
        "password": "pwd",
        "undelete": "false"
    }
session = requests.Session()
session.post("https://discord.com/api/v9/auth/login", json=payload, headers=header)
```

In the headers I included Content-Type, Content-Length, User-Agent, X-Fingerprint and X-Super-Properties.
I dont realy have an idea of what I am doing I just included everything that seemed important. I am only reseving a response 400. Should I incloude something else to make it work? or exclude?